Do stainless steel crown staples sometimes have a yellow tint, like mechanically galvanized?
I ordered some collated stainless steel crown staples to install red cedar shingles, as I didn't want the fasteners to bleed and stain the shingles. When they arrived, they were tinted yellow like some mechanically galvanized "zinc yellow" fasteners.  Is this yellow tint on stainless steel  staples normal?

Can just be the adhesive used to bind them together.

did you try scratching

Does the box say stainless?

@Traveler Yes, I did. I had scratched the long side of the collation. But the yellow didn't come off. However, when I moved to the first staple in the collation, after reading your comment, and scratched its face (like looking into a tunnel opening) the yellow did come off to reveal a silver layer underneath.

The box didn't have any sort of tamper-proof seal, so I didn't want to rely on what the box said. It was purchased online, not from a brick-and-mortar store.
